Undefined dependencies when implement circular dependencies when using @UseGuards in controller
I'm using NestJS for my app and using the @UseGuards(). I also created 2 guards for my controller like:
JwtAuthGuard:
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';

export class JwtAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt') {}

ApiKeyGuard:
@Injectable()
export class ApiKeyGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private configService: ConfigService) {}

  canActivate (context: ExecutionContext) {
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    const { apikey } = request.headers;

    if (apikey === env.get('API_KEY')) return true;
    else throw new UnauthorizedException();
  }
}

This my Controller:
@Get('/:users')
  @UseGuards(ApiKeyGuard)
  getUser(): {
    return this.userService.getUser();
  }

and the services look like:
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor(private dummyService:DummyService) {}

  getUser() {
    return this.dummyService.getUser();
  }

Here is the module.ts file:
@Module({
  imports: [...],
  controllers: [userController],
  providers: [....],
  exports: [UserService],
})
export class CouponModule {}

I also have another module named CouponModule has CouponController which is also used that @UseGuard() and its services: the CouponService is circular dependencies with the UserService and also use the DummyService as well
Problem:
All the API that has the @UseGuards(ApiKeyGuard) in the controller are returning error when the app processing requests:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getUser' of undefined

But when I use the @UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard) for that API, the app worked normally and no error was thrown. Even when I removed the @UseGuards() decorator, the error happened again.
I also tried to add that DummyServices to the providers of the module.ts file for both but it does not solve the problem.
I've done lots of searching and investigating and still can not found any the root cause or the solution for this.

Maybe the issue arises from a circular dependency that needs time to load all the necessary dependencies (providers, services,…)
The JwtAuthGuard you implemented needs time to get the token then validate it, and give the space for all the necessary dependencies to be loaded, that’s why your app works normally when using it.
The apiKeyGuards is just different, with the simple logic (text compare only), it completes the validation and lets the request go through before other dependencies are completely loaded, that’s why you get undefined.
The solution is simple, just slow down the api key validation a little bit by using the sleep() function as below
//api-key.strategy.ts
@Injectable()
export class ApiKeyStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'apiKey') {
  constructor(private readonly authService: AuthService) {
    super();
  }

  async validate(request: string): Promise<void> {
    await sleep(0);
    const isValid = await this.authService.validateApiKey(request);
    if (!isValid) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException('Invalid API Key');
    }
    return user
  }

  override async authenticate(request: Request): Promise<void> {
    if (!apiKey) {
      this.fail('API Key is missing');
      return;
    }

    try {
    const user =   await this.validate(apiKey);
      this.success(user);
    } catch (error) {
      this.fail(error);
    }
  }
}


//sleep.ts
export function sleep(ms: number, fn?: () => void) {
  return new Promise((res) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      fn?.();
      res('process is sleeping!');
    }, ms);
  });
}


Nice approach, but can it still using the CanActive() instead of create a new strategy?

I attempted, but it is not functioning.

I think the problem is configService which is injected in ApiKeyGuard
Just to be sure,delete the injection from constructor.If it's running fine check does configService global or not

I tried what you mentioned and the error still happens. I think the problems is my JwtAuthGuard. Because, which I mentioned in the post, even when I remove the @UseGuards(), the error happens. But when I use the @UseGuards() only with JwtAuthGuard, the app works normally
